# Inline Javascript Mp3 player help

Tags: javascript, mp3

Can anyone identify what MP3 player is used on this website?

http://clone.nl/

I've looked in the source and can see Soundmanager2 referenced aswell as a 3rd party script at http://clone.nl/js/Player.js

Alternatively, can anyone recommend a similair player - basically I want something that is a textlink that will drop out into an mp3 player when clicked

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you could use a modified version of this player to achieve your effect.

http://www.sean-o.com/jquery/jmp3/

Keep in mind that on less modern browsers, any JS player will have to fall back on flash.  (which is usually fine in older browsers anyways).

Comment: Cheers for the help, that looks ideal

Answer (score 2):

As always it's flash, until HTML5 is more widely supported it's the only reliable way to play sound/video on a webpage.

The sound manager referenced is located here: http://schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Their website provides a bunch of examples that implement the style of player you want.